# Continuous function property

Tags: analysis, functions, continuity, metric-spaces

I'm having trouble understanding some properties of continuous function.

$f:X \to Y$ is continuous if $ \forall~ x_{1} \in X ~~\forall \epsilon > 0 ~ \exists \delta > 0 ~~d_{X}(x,x_{1}) < \delta \implies d_{Y}(f(x),f(x_{1}) < \epsilon$

If $x_{1}$ is a point of accumulation, then $f(x_{1})$ is also a point of accumulation.

$d(k,x_{1})<d(j,x_{1}) \nRightarrow d(f(k),f(x_{1}))<d(f(j),f(x_{1})) $ makes sense to me but I think that for really really close point the "order" is preserved, this doesn't exclude that there could be other random point really really close to $f(x_{1})$ that are far away from $x_{1}$.

I really appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: What you wrote is *not* the definition of continuity. In fact, with that definition, *every* function between metric spaces would be continuous

Comment: I tried to fix it, could you take a look at it. Thanks for the time